# problem/ text on real analysis topics.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

i am interested in **Real Analysis** topics:

1.limit points
2. interior points
3. boundry points
4. isolated points
5. connected sets
6. compact sets

I have read and texts and have some sense of idea what 1.limit points
2. interior points
3. boundry points
4. isolated points are.

But i havn't found any text with sufficient details to tackle problems on connected sets and complete sets in Real Numbers.Please provide suggestions on relevent text and problem book on above 6 topics.

Comment: Apostol's Mathematical Analysis Text handles the above fairly well. In fact, there are quite a few references to good analysis texts on this site.

Comment: Well the first book that comes to mind is Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, aka Baby Rudin. 
As said before Apostol's Mathematical Analysis is also a good book. It contains more material (especially regarding connectedness, which Rudin dedicates very little space to) than Rudin and is a little bit more friendly with the reader, while Rudin always goes for the slickest, most elegant proof.